# Android instrumentation test only works for app module

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

I a have multi module android app. I need to write some instrumentation test for my app but only instrumentation test from `app` module are working. These tests run fine and either pass or fail but instrumentation test from other module are not even recognized.

I use `assembleAndroidTest` gradle task to build instrumentation test APK, the install is with adb and run `adb shell am instrument -w com.example.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` to run test.

For the result I only see test which are in `app` module. I analyzed generated APK but only tests from `app` module were included.

I even used android studio to specifically run test in other modules but i faced message below:

[image]